# Get an imediate UPS responce from APC ups

Tags: power-management, battery, ups

I have an APC UPS with my Ubuntu system and I have it configured with apcupsd. The UPS works fine but when the power goes out, it takes a while for the system to alert me of a outage or to properly shut down the system. If the power flashes on and off for an example,my system will indicate that the UPS is discharging then recharging a while after the outage occurred. Within the configuration file of apcupsd, there is a pool time counter that supposedly updated the UPS every now and then(in seconds). Witch I have set for 1. but if I unplug my UPS the response is more than a second.

Is there a way to configure the UPS to send a immediate response?